# How to reissue a currency you own in NXT Monetary System (Sidechains)?

Tags: nxt, sidechains

I registered a monetary system currency on the NXT platform and made it exchangable as one of the properties. But now I want to make it reservable for a crowdfunding campaign. How do you reissue the same currency on the NXT platform? I dont see a reissue button anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not distributed any coins, you can reissue the currency the same way you issued it by following this [guide](https://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Monetary_System#Issue_a_Currency).

Comment: So does this mean I have to pay the 1000 nxt fee again? or if i purchased a 25000 nxt coin i have to pay that? Or is it a lower fee?

Comment: The reissue fee is always 40 NXT.

Comment: the fee doesn't update to 40 when reissuing a coin i have. do i have to do it manually?

Comment: Yes, click on "advanced" and change the fee to 40 NXT. It will be accepted. I updated the wiki guide thanks to your question.

Comment: thanks! great work on the docs... there's still alot of nxt questions here that need some love.